# iOS - getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in using AQGridView with Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, gridview, aqgridview

I am using AQGridView with Xib file. I have set the basic Project just as explained in the [**Video**](https://vimeo.com/46408155) by `Evadne Wu`. And i am moving to next Grid using *`expandFromRect`* from **ExpansionDemo**  and the Grid is loaded fine but whenever i click anywhere on the grid i get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and exception is generated without any Log about the reason.

Also that the `didSelectItemAtIndex`  **doesn't get called** even though i have set the `self.gridView.delegate = self;`

Comment: try setting exception break point.

Comment: as i have mentioned that the `didSelectItemAtIndex` doesn't get called  which is supposed to be called so how could i set a breakpoint?

Comment: "Exception break point" and just break point are not the same. Refer http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions. Exception breakpoint will help you pointing out the line of code which is throwing that error.

Comment: @Norbert okay let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is resolved. One thing that i haven't read [Known Bugs](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView#known-bugs) while setting up **AQGridView** i.e. `do not pile multiple animations on top of one another` that was the main reason i was facing the issue. So, while the grid was animating i blocked start of any other grid Animation and hence the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

```
self.gridView.dataSource = self;
```

Try this.

EDIT: This usually ensures that the delegate methods are getting called. :)

Comment: Please check the question carefully. I have already added that.

Comment: You've said you set up self.gridView.delegate. I'm talking about self.gridView.dataSource.

Comment: dataSource was obviously added. That's why i said **Grid is loaded fine**. Please check the question carefully again